# apache ant build.xml:577: Unable to find a javac compiler

Tags: java, ant

Any idea?
There are ton of posts out of there but I didn't find any solution for mac, yet.
I've downloaded the ant source code and trying to run the build but no success here. I found some posts saying about set the JAVA_HOME with JDK but this is something I did...
no thought here so any input would be appreciated

```
myMac:apache-ant-1.9.7 mauri$ pwd
/Users/mauri/Downloads/apache-ant-1.9.7
myMac:apache-ant-1.9.7 mauri$ l
total 1032
drwxr-xr-x@  8 mauri  wheel   272B  9 Abr  2016 src
-rw-r--r--@  1 mauri  wheel   1,9K  9 Abr  2016 patch.xml
-rw-r--r--@  1 mauri  wheel   4,3K  9 Abr  2016 get-m2.xml
-rw-r--r--@  1 mauri  wheel    11K  9 Abr  2016 fetch.xml
-rw-r--r--@  1 mauri  wheel    29K  9 Abr  2016 contributors.xml
-rw-r--r--@  1 mauri  wheel    75K  9 Abr  2016 build.xml
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 mauri  wheel   1,7K  9 Abr  2016 build.sh
-rw-r--r--@  1 mauri  wheel   1,6K  9 Abr  2016 build.bat
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 mauri  wheel   4,4K  9 Abr  2016 bootstrap.sh
-rw-r--r--@  1 mauri  wheel   4,4K  9 Abr  2016 bootstrap.bat
-rw-r--r--@  1 mauri  wheel   228K  9 Abr  2016 WHATSNEW
-rw-r--r--@  1 mauri  wheel   4,0K  9 Abr  2016 README
-rw-r--r--@  1 mauri  wheel   305B  9 Abr  2016 NOTICE
-rw-r--r--@  1 mauri  wheel    15K  9 Abr  2016 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--@  1 mauri  wheel    90K  9 Abr  2016 KEYS
-rw-r--r--@  1 mauri  wheel   126B  9 Abr  2016 INSTALL
-rw-r--r--@  1 mauri  wheel   5,9K  9 Abr  2016 CONTRIBUTORS
drwxr-xr-x@ 49 mauri  wheel   1,6K 15 Dez 23:43 manual
drwxr-xr-x@  5 mauri  wheel   170B 15 Dez 23:43 lib
myMac:apache-ant-1.9.7 mauri$ sh build.sh
... Bootstrapping Ant Distribution
... Compiling Ant Classes
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
... Copying Required Files
... Building Ant Distribution
Buildfile: /Users/mauri/Downloads/apache-ant-1.9.7/build.xml

bootstrap:

prepare:

check_for_optional_packages:

build:
Created dir: /Users/mauri/Downloads/apache-ant-1.9.7/build/lib

BUILD FAILED
/Users/mauri/Downloads/apache-ant-1.9.7/build.xml:1078: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/mauri/Downloads/apache-ant-1.9.7/build.xml:577: Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home/jre"

Total time: 0 seconds
... Failed Building Ant Distribution !
Bootstrap FAILED
myMac:apache-ant-1.9.7 mauri$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
myMac:apache-ant-1.9.7 mauri$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_111
myMac:apache-ant-1.9.7 mauri$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home
myMac:apache-ant-1.9.7 mauri$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.11.6
BuildVersion:   15G1004
myMac:apache-ant-1.9.7 mauri$ which javac
/usr/bin/javac
myMac:apache-ant-1.9.7 mauri$ ls -l /usr/bin/javac
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  75 16 Abr  2016 /usr/bin/javac -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/javac
myMac:apache-ant-1.9.7 mauri$ file /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/javac
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/javac: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/javac (for architecture i386):    Mach-O executable i386
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/javac (for architecture x86_64):  Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

I've tried to change the JAVA_HOME pointing to the JDK but ant is trying to use java in bin but doesn't work because in MAC is within the path Contents/Home

```
myMac:apache-ant-1.9.7 mauri$ export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk
myMac:apache-ant-1.9.7 mauri$ sh build.sh 
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/bin/java
Bootstrap FAILED
myMac:apache-ant-1.9.7 mauri$ ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/bin/java
ls: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

Comment: can you show the respective build script?

Comment: is the default one: http://apache.mirrors.ionfish.org//ant/source/apache-ant-1.9.7-src.zip

Comment: I'm not sure on how it is deployed on Mac system, but usualy JAVA_HOME has to point to the directory containing the JDK distribution . In your case it should be '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk' whereas it seems to point to '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home/jre' (which is a jre and may not contain javac program)

Comment: @P.A.Cros I've tried but didn't work. I've just updated the first post. thanks for the note